# REGEXP pattern for matching 2 different symbols

Tags: php, regex

I need that if string contains symbols `.` AND `@` that print yes, queue symbols does not matters, important that in string will be this symbols at least one times, I need make this using regexp.

I write:

```
if (preg_match("#(\@.*\.)|(\..*\@)#",$str)) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

But I doubt that can write more easy pattern for this

Comment: My spidey sense says your trying to validate an email address?

Comment: Not a regex, but this is always an option: `if (strpos($str, "@") !== false && strpos($str, ".") !== false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex `(?=.*\.)(?=.*@).+`

```
(?=.*\.) dot exists
(?=.*@) @ exists
.+ any string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead to separate the two conditions:

```
^(?=.*\.)(?=.*@)
```

The start-of-string anchor is not needed, but it helps performance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its a bit easier without a regex.

```
if(strpos($str, ".") !== false || strpos($str, "@") !== false) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Then you don't need the regex is perhaps a bit faster. Then you only search if a character is in a string.